# how to Sql Table Data using in switch statement?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table in the SQL database with two columns. I want to use that data in a switch case loop as

```
switch(Inputvalue) {
case row1.column1:
    return row1.column2;
case row2.column1:
    return row2.column2;
.
.
.
case rowN.column1:
    return rowN.column2;
}
```

if possible in view using javascript or else in controller using c#

[image]

so the program for switch loop is like

```
switch(Inputvalue) {
case  1:
    return Hyderabad;
case 2:
    return Chennai;
case 3:
    return Banglore;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is strange, basically you are asking for a method that returns the name of a city from your table with a given ID. So why don't you use sql as tagged? Presuming sql-server:

```
public static string GetCityName(int cityId)
{
    string sql = "SELECT Name FROM City WHERE Id = @Id";
    using(var con = new SqlConnection("Insert Your Connection String"))
    {
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cityId;
            string name = (string) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is useful for you

```
    CASE expression

   WHEN value_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN value_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN value_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with Switch-Case, instead of it you can use dictionary for lookup like below:

```
var lookUp = yourDataTable.AsEnumrable().ToDictionary(r => r.column1, k => k.column2);
var result = lookUp[value];
```